# Character rotates 90 degrees and changes location in edit mode

Tags: rigging, edit-mode, pose-mode, mixamo

I have a character that I rigged with mixamo and I want to edit the mesh. When I try to edit it, the model rotates 90 degrees and changes location. I have the character in "rest position" but If I try to rotate the character when in edit mode and then go back to "pose position" I end up with deformations and bones in the wrong locations. I want to be able to edit the character mesh without the character moving and rotating and then without it changing the location of the bones.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `rotation` of the mesh and the rig in `object mode`, this might be the issue you're facing.

(Im sorry I don't have enough reputation score to comment, so I'm posting the answer)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, but thank you. This just causes further deformation.